# Pin filter like snapchat

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone help in implementing Pin Filter like in snapchat or instagram ?

I just want to set an image on the point inside the video. 
For example I am setting an image on fingertip in video and as the fingertip moves the image also moves with it

Comment: Please do not ask "How do I do what that other app does?" Describe  what you want to do, maybe include an image or two if that makes it clear, ***and*** describe what you've tried to do so far. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DonMag I just want to set an image on the point inside the video.
For example I am setting an image on finger tip in video and as the finger tip moves the image also moves with it.